# Passing data between 2 child components in React without reloading the components

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component A with 3 child components: B, C, and D. Component D renders a react-tabulator table and creates a ref for the table. How can I pass this ref from component D to components B and C without using state variables in A or D? Using state variables causes components to be re-rendered and the table is re-created, leading to an infinite loop.

This is how the code for component A looks like:

```
export const A = () => {
    return (
        <B var1={var1}>
        <C var2={var2}>
        <D var3={var3}>
    )
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: maybe use contexts [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)